# php получить ключ массива

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив

```
Array (
    [47] => Array (
        [pageName] => Основная версия
        [pageMeta] => main
        [betaId] =>
    )
)
```

хочу получить его ключ "47" , как это сделать? простейшая проверка на значение не срабатывает

```
if(in_array("main",$pages)) echo 123;
```

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста var_dump($pages);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Варианты поиска.

По ключу:

```
reset($pages);
$firstKey = key($pages);

if (in_array('main', $pages[$firstKey])) {
    // нашли 'main'...
} else {
    // не нашли 'main'...
}
```

Проходом по массиву:

```
foreach ($pages as $key => $value)
{
    if (in_array('main', $value)) {
        // нашли 'main'...
    } else {
        // не нашли 'main'...
    }
}
```

Более универсальный способ проверки значений, подходит для вложенных массивов:

```
function check($array, $value)
{
    foreach ($array as $key => $inner) {
        if (is_array($inner)) {
            if (check($inner, $value)) {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            if ($value == $inner) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Использование:

```
if (check($pages, 'main')) {
     // нашли 'main'...
} else {
     // не нашли 'main'...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

вы ищите в верхнем уровне массива, так работать не будет. а так должно:

```
foreach($pages as $k=>$v) {
   if(in_array("main",$v)) {
       echo $k;
       break;
}
```